# Database select all angular websql in service, get the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-promise

How to put that code in service? (this is from https://github.com/paulocaldeira17/angular-websql) I mean I want to pass table name and then get the array with users. I think I should use promises but I have no idea how to start.

```
$scope.db.selectAll("table_users", function(results) {
  $scope.users = [];
  for(var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
     $scope.users.push(results.rows.item(i));
  }
  $scope.$apply();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use promises for websql operations.

```
SampleService.getUsers("table_name").then(function(){
  console.log("Array of users");
});
```

**Service**

```
getUsers:function(table_name){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $scope.db.selectAll("table_users", function(results) {
  $scope.users = [];
  for(var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
     $scope.users.push(results.rows.item(i));
  }
   deferred.resolve($scope.users);
});
  return deferred.promise;

}
```

The code is not the actual one,but it will give you an overall idea to solve the problem.

Some Reference for using $q promises in angularjs

1. [Promises explained as cartoon](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html)
2. [From Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)
3. http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/04/angularjspart-11-promises/

Comment: Thanks! But I always have problem with .then(function(){}) in controllers, because the code in then is out of scope of the rest controller. Although I use state provider where is great thing- resolve, which solves dependency but in case where I don't use state provider, how to deal with that problem?

Comment: Just clicked on add comment too fast ;-)